# How do I get Mono to use the right 'ToolsVersion'?

Tags: c#, ubuntu, mono

```
XBuild Engine Version 12.0
Mono, Version 3.2.8.0
```

I'm trying to build my C# solution in XBuild. It builds absolutely fine in Windows, but not on Ubuntu. I get the following errors:

```
warning : Project has unknown ToolsVersion '14.0'. Using the default tools version '4.0' instead.
Target GetFrameworkPaths:
/usr/lib/mono/4.5/Microsoft.Common.targets:  warning : TargetFrameworkVersion 'v4.5.2' not supported by this toolset (ToolsVersion: 4.0).
error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'RedditSharp' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
error CS0246: The type or namespace name `IReadOnlyCollection' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
```

and similar. I have added RedditSharp.dll to the GAC, so I don't know why it can't find it, and I certainly don't know why it can't find IReadOnlyCollection. I have a suspicion that it's all because I can't use ToolsVersion 14.0.

Does anybody know anything about building C# on Linux? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7):

14 means MSBuild 14, which is part of Visual Studio 2015. Usually Mono xbuild only supports the latest Visual Studio release **after a while**. So you either wait till it is updated, or hack xbuild if you like.

Another workaround is to convert your projects to MSBuild version 12

Answer (score 5):

You are facing two different issues.

First the warnings about ToolsVersion 14.0 and second the errors complaining 4.5.2 not being supported.

Simply change the target framework to 4.5 and your project will compile. ToolsVersion warnings are still there, but compilation will finish successfully.

I ran into the same problem. After changing the target framework all works fine.

Comment: Even now 1.5 years on I still need to downgrade the .Net framework to 4.5 for projects to be run under MONO?

Answer (score 0):

I have the [Debian 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian#Release_timeline) (Jessie) version of Raspbian with Mono 5.0 installed.

Apparently upgrading [MonoDevelop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MonoDevelop) doesn't help. So I went to the folder containing the .sln file, found the .csproj file and modified the Toolsversion (it should be on the top lines of the file) there from "15.0" to "4.0". That worked.